# View must get dynamically build path from a helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have the following link in a View:

```
<li><%= link_to "Classrooms", '/institutes/1/courses' %></li>
```

I want to get path "'/institutes/1/courses'" from a helper method. Please let me know how I do that, and I can call the helper in my View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to your class helper and call it directly there. For example, if your model call "posts", you can have a file posts_helper.rb inside your helpers folder with something like

```
module PostsHelper
  def your_method
  end
end
```

and in your view,

```
<li><%= link_to "Classrooms", your_method %></li>
```

You can also add it to application_helper.rb, but you should do that only if you intend to use it globally.

Comment: Just came across url_helpers. Do you know how I can use that to solve this problem?

Comment: try add "include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers" where you intend to use it. But url helper should be available on all views, I believe

Comment: Thanks, but where do I create this mapping if I am using url_helpers?

Comment: you must the define your routes on routes.rb file (config folder). For example, a path for posts: get "/posts" => "posts#index", as: :posts. Where the first one is the path, the second "controller#action" and the last one is the name of the method that returns the path to you. So, in that case, you could use posts_path (add the sufix "_path" to the symbol you set in as:) in your view and it should return "/posts"